# To use the conditional branch (If statements) to obtain the time

Tags: swift, swift2

We want to assign the result Once at 23:00 to number 1, but does not move the following source.
Perhaps, I think not been able conversion of type String.
I want you to tell me the solution

```
import UIKit
let now = NSDate() // gettime
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ja_JP") 
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh" // o`clock
print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(now)) // convert to String
if now = 23 {
   number1 = result
   result = 0
 }
```

Comment: `if now = 23 {` does not compile in Swift. Where are `result` and `number1` defined? – This cannot be your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let now = NSDate() // gettime
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
// If you want to know the hour in a particular time zone, set it here.
// For example, to get the time in Japan:
// calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "Asia/Tokyo")!
// By default, the calendar uses the system time zone setting.
let hour = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: now)
if hour == 23 {
    print("It is the appointed hour.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My app complete!

Comment: If I have solved your problem, please click the check mark to the left of my answer.